# StreamBuilder for Amplify Auth State on flutter?

Tags: flutter, stream-builder, bottom-navigation-bar, amplify-auth-cognito

Trying to update BottomNavigationBarItems based on user successful signUp/signIn.
Not an expert in flutter or AWS, but have tried using either of the following to update a bool flag to render `_listA` or `_listB`

- `Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()`
- `Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser()`

The problem I'm having is the `BottomNavigationBar` renders faster than the above functions and app needs to reload to show the correct bar items.

Is there a solution like the following?

```
bottomNavigationBar: StreamBuilder<SomeState>(
   stream: Amplify.Auth.SomeState,
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
     return BottomNavigationBar(
...
```

Any other alternative would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use a `StreamBuilder` for this job, but you can use `StreamsubScription` for auth events:

```
final subscription = Amplify.Hub.listen(HubChannel.Auth,(AuthHubEvent event) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case AuthHubEventType.signedIn:
      safePrint('User is signed in.');
      break;
    case AuthHubEventType.signedOut:
      safePrint('User is signed out.');
      break;
    case AuthHubEventType.sessionExpired:
      safePrint('The session has expired.');
      break;
    case AuthHubEventType.userDeleted:
      safePrint('The user has been deleted.');
      break;
  }
});
```

You can read the documentation for more information: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/auth-events/q/platform/flutter/